# "Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Request is missing required authentication credential" when using ScriptService

Tags: c#, .net, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Using .net, I'm trying to make a request to the Google ScriptService, however I keep getting this error "Request is missing required authentication credential", although I am including the credential. In fact I use the same credential not too long before to successfully make a request to the YoutubeService.

Below is my code, it actually used to work, so I'm not sure what has changed:

```
Scopes = new string[] { ScriptService.Scope.Forms, ScriptService.Scope.Spreadsheets,
            ScriptService.Scope.Drive, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };

UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"Resources\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var credPath = Path.Combine(parentDir, ".credentials/" + folderName);

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
         GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
         Scopes,
         "user",
         CancellationToken.None,
         new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}

// Create Google Apps Script Execution API service.
var service = new ScriptService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = this.credential,
    ApplicationName = Properties.Resources.ApplicationName,
 });

// Create an execution request object.
ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest();
request.Function = "createForm";
request.Parameters = new List<object>();
request.Parameters.Add(this.id);
request.Parameters.Add(name);
request.Parameters.Add(email);
request.Parameters.Add(this.link);

ScriptsResource.RunRequest runReq = service.Scripts.Run(request, Globals.Script_ID);

try
{
    // Make the API request.
    Operation op = runReq.Execute();
catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error calling API:\n{0}", e.ToString());
}
```

I have enabled the API and generated OAuth 2.0 credentials for my platform in the developer console. The client_secret.json is the OAuth 2.0 credential that I downloaded from my console.

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong? I recall having a similar issue after updating my google packages, however in this instance I did not do so. I also tried updating the packages and still got the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like you need to update the authorization scopes you request, or perhaps you need to perform the authorization flow. When you added the Execution API to your project, did you include any new scopes?

Comment: This was indeed my issue, thank you! I thought I added the necessary scopes, as this has worked before, but after checking again, I was missing the UserInfoEmail authorization scope.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and accept it (i.e. compare the before/after for the scopes definitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not have the correct authorization scopes. Originally I had:

```
Scopes = new string[] { ScriptService.Scope.Forms, ScriptService.Scope.Spreadsheets,
        ScriptService.Scope.Drive, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };
```

However, upon checking the "Scopes" tab in my apps script Project Properties, I was missing the "userinfo.email" scope. And so, I updated my code in the following way:

```
Scopes = new string[] { ScriptService.Scope.Forms, ScriptService.Scope.Spreadsheets,
        ScriptService.Scope.Drive, ScriptService.Scope.UserinfoEmail, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };
```

My guess is that the API had been updated since I originally wrote my script some months ago, as I was able to successfully run it at that time with the three original authorizations that I had.